# How do I sort a DynamicFrame by date in AWS Glue?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I've CSV in S3 that looks as follows:

```
firstname,lastname,birthdate
john,doe,9/15/1994
marise,deit,1/20/1990
lora,saint,6/7/1992
```

and I'd like to sort its rows by `birthdate` and put the resulting CSV back into S3 using AWS Glue. This is what I've written so far:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

myCSV = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={
        "quoteChar": '"',
        "withHeader": True,
        "separator": ",",
        "optimizePerformance": False,
    },
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": [
            "S3-PATH-TO-CSV"
        ]
    },
    transformation_ctx="myCSV",
)

sortedCSV = myCSV.toDF().sort("birthdate")

# repartition into a single CSV file.
repartitionedDF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(sortedCSV, glueContext, "repartitionedDF")
repartitionedDF = repartitionedDF.repartition(1)

outputCSV = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=repartitionedDF,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "path": "OUTPATH-S3",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    transformation_ctx="outputCSV",
)

job.commit()
```

When I run it, the rows aren't sorted by date. Since the values in `birthdate` are strings, this leads me to believe I must somehow convert them to a date object or its Python equivalent, however I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark.sql.function` has a `to_date method` that you can use.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
sortedCSV = myCSV.toDF().withColumn("date_column", to_date(df["birthdate"], "MM-dd-yyyy").cast(DateType())).sort("date_column")
```

`sortedCsv` will now be sorted based on the birthdate but will have an addtional column called `date_column`